# Implementation of interface through inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have an interface that requires the square brackets operator to be implemented. The class that inherits from this implements it. However,it also inherits from Dictionary<>, where that same operator is implemented:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IBar this[String tFooName] { get; }
}


[Serializable]
public class ConcreteFoo: Dictionary<String, Bar>, IFoo
{
    // Implement interface by calling the dictionary
    public IBar this[String tFooName] { get { return this[tFooName]; } }



    // .... more code ....
}
```

When I try to use the code, the compiler references the immediate interface that was implemented and says that I cannot assign to it:

```
MyClass[tKeyStr] = new Bar();
```

The error is correct. So, I removed my implementation of the IFoo interface and hoped that by inheriting from Dictionary<>, it would be auto-implemented. It has not panned out the way I wanted.

I get the error 'does not implement interface member ...'.

How would I solve this without making the dictionary a private member?? Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it really *need* to derive from `Dictionary<string, Bar>`? In my experience it's rarely a good idea to derive directly from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `List<T>` etc - only the collections which have been *explicitly designed* for inheritance (e.g. [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx)) usually work well as a fit for inheritance.

Can you not just make your `ConcreteFoo` have a `Dictionary<string, Bar>` *field* instead? You sort of allude to that in your final question, but it's not clear *why* you're trying to use inheritance instead of composition.

If you really *must* use inheritance, you can use [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx), like this:

```
IBar IFoo.this[String tFooName] { get { return this[tFooName]; } }
```

... but I would suggest favouring composition instead.

Comment: My reason is that this object IS a dictionary with a few added methods and fields. I slimmed down the code for brevity.

Comment: @MarkP: I would still suggest using composition, but implementing your interface and `IDictionary<string, Bar>`.  This will be nicer over time than subclassing `Dictionary<T,U>`.

Comment: @MarkP: Is it necessary that code which is expecting a Dictionary accept your type just as well?  If so, then inheritance is proper.  if not, composition is better.